# Memcached node error

Tags: node.js, caching, memcached

I am using memcached to cache a json string.

as I send my request from the client side and i get in the server side i have the `request` variable.

```
memcached.get(request, function(err, result) {
        if (result != null) {
            console.log("served by memcached");
            res.json(result);
        } else {
         process_request(request,function(err,result){
             res.json(result);
             memcached.set(request, json, lifetime, function(err, result) {});
         });
        }
});
```

but it seems that it is not getting into memcached. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest making experiments and doing the math yourself. If something goes wrong, "but some guy from the internets told me to use this" is a pretty lame excuse :)

Comment: Since you already use redis, there will be less friction if you go this route

Comment: I was hoping for something like, "I have used that for a similar occasion" or  your keys are too big and will have negative impact or something. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why your keys are so big, though?

Comment: I use the data from the json to create an image, of which i will be sending back the path. 
the request contains the data used to create that image, and could be quite a lot in some occasions.

Comment: Can't you create a hash of the data used to create the image and use that for the key?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sounds like something out of Little Red Riding Hood ;)